# Changing pairs in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I tried to change a pair in a vertex from the loop in "setEdge" function but failed.
Is there another way to change the value of the pair[1]?

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.neighbors = []
    def addNeighbor(self, v, w=0):
        self.neighbors.append((v,w))

def setEdge(self, frm, to, w):
    if frm not in self.vertexes:
        self.addVertex(frm)
    if to not in self.vertexes:
        self.addVertex(to)
    for v in self.vertexes:
        if v == frm:
            for t in v.neighbors:
                if t[0] == to:
                    newWeight = t[1] + w
                    t = (to, newWeight)
                    break
            v.addNeighbor(to, w)
```

problem here - not changing t value:

```
if t[0] == to:
    newWeight = t[1] + w
    t = (to, newWeight)
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set variable t to another value but don't mutate it so the value in neighbors remains the same.

Try something around those lines:

```
        for i, t in enumerate(v.neighbors):
            if t[0] == to:
                newWeight = t[1] + w
                t = (to, newWeight)
                v.neighbours[i] = t
                break
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Welcome to SO. No need to add "SOLVED" to the subject. Accepting an answer is enough to let others know it is answered. You may also upvote answers using the up arrow close to the answer score.